# Excel Formula for If Statement to Decide Status in Leveling Condition

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

i've been trying to get status in cell based on reference value A3:A. The reference value compare to another column with several level.
But it seems my logic seems a bit off as if i put reference value a number, the result in B3:B is either give a result or give #value result. I've attached the note problem and [link to the google doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1emnj46heqTe83ElQLt_gUhO9EptSp9mpn5Fn9JhTfpk/edit?usp=sharing).

Any clue or solution will be great. Thank you

here's my formula =if(and($A5<=C5,$A5>D5),C$1,if(and($A5<=D5,$A5>E5),D$1,if(and($A5<=E5,$A5>F5),E$1,if(and($A5<=F5,$A5>G5),F$1,if(and($A5<=G5,$A5>=H5),G$1,if(and($A5<H5,$A5>=I5),H$1,if(and($A5<I5,$A5>J5),I$1,if(and($A5<=J5,$A5>K5),J$1,if(and($A5<=K5,$A5>L5),K$1,if(and($A5<=L5,$A5>M5),L$1,if(and($A5<=M5,$A5>N5),M$1,if(and($A5<=N5,$A5>=O5),N$1,if(and($A5<O5,$A5>=P5),O$1,if(and($A5<P5,$A5>AC5),P$1,if(and($A5>=Q5,$A5<R5),Q$1,if(and($A5>=R5,$A5<S5),R$1,if(and($A5>=S5,$A5<T5),S$1,if(and($A5>=T5,$A5<U5),T$1,if(and($A5>=U5,$A5<V5),U$1,if(and($A5>=V5,$A5<W5),V$1,if(and($A5<=AC5),AC$1,if(and($A5>=W5,$A5<X5),W$1,if(and($A5>=X5,$A5<Y5),X$1,if(and($A5>=Y5,$A5<Z5),Y$1,if(and($A5>=Z5,$A5<AA5),Z$1,if(and($A5>=AA5,$A5<AB5),AA$1,if($A5>=AB5,AB$1,"")))))))))))))))))))))))))))

[Note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMG9v.png)

i expect the formula can be optimized so it will give a status for any reference value , not a #value.

If any modification or better suggestion arise, it will be great.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Like this it is very hard to understand your requirement, it would help, if you provide some _sample_ data and your _expected output_. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I do lots of things with if() and my first point is that any more than 3 levels then you should change the approach. A lookup table might be better here - both for control of how it works and testing as well as future editing.

Comment: Can't you find your data using the `Match()` worksheet function (but instead of "Exact match", use a "smaller than" or "larger than" option)?

Comment: thank you @Ike , i've been sharing google doc link as references for my question above in the body.

Comment: Well, i've been very fond of index and match. But just can't arrange how to use match as question. Might be good if any example approach given to try. Thank you

Comment: "i've been sharing google doc link": it is no good practice to share links - no serious developer who might be able to help you will open it. Please read the links I provided.

Comment: So sorry for the way i ask the question, not so familiar with adding question. I've tried to attach the code in the body and try to recreate the MRE in google doc. After looking up in your link, please advise for future question about example in google doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I show a different approach, which I consider to be much easier to control and edit that many nested if() statements:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Solar Mike , that's awesome insight and it didn't come to my mind at first. So the vlookup itself will match to the nearest number or just previous number position? Other things on my question is, is it applicable to a situation where there's duplicate number in below row that gives a result too?

Comment: So you can replace the false with true for an exact match, worth playing with these functions and their arguments. You should have little trouble since you are so familiar with index() and match() as you say in your comment - match uses 1,0 and -1 for the sorting arguments.

Comment: I've tried it and it works. It gives me better approach on this one. Thank you